# I am not able to run date datatype as SQL query in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I have imported an Excel file in MS Access 2007 having date formated as `dd-mm-yyyy`. When I run the following query

```
SELECT Hours
FROM work_DA WHERE Date BETWEEN 01-05-2013 AND 09-5-2013;
```

I get only blank table with Hours field.
Please tell me how to run this query in MS Access.

Comment: What data type is the MS Access field `Date`?

Comment: What is the structure of the work_DA table?

Answer (score -1):

Try this ..

sqlcommand is

```
"SELECT Hours FROM work_DA WHERE Date >= #" & format(01-05-2013,'dd-mm-yyyy') & _
"# AND Date <= #" & format(09-5-2013,'dd-mm-yyyy') & "#"
```

change the dates with variables

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if you mentioned your table structure.
From what I can figure, you have to use **"FORMAT"** function when you query the date.